# W3 Total cache "empty all caches" and no stylesheets render

Tags: plugins, plugin-w3-total-cache, css

I have the w3 Total cache plugin installed and so far its been great as I'm sure you will all agree, so thanks to the author for an amazing plugin. However, I used the "empty all caches" button on the general settings page and when the plugin is activated none of my stylesheets are loading so the page appears without any styling?

I have to deactivate the plugin for the stylesheets to load. How can I reactivate W3 so that the stylesheets all render properly again?

Comment: Stylesheets are never rendered. Do you mean they are not loaded? Have you tested their URLs?

Comment: My theme's style.css wasn't present when viewing the source of the page. So yes you are right its not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3 Total Cache combines .css files. If you do not want this to happen, deactivate the option on the page `wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_minify`, section CSS `enable`.

If this option is not available, try setting the `minify` settings on the main page of W3 Total Cache to `manual`.

This Caching Plugin is awesome - but you have to tweak the settings quite a bit, if you are new to it mostly through trial and error, to get to the best result.

Please be sure to check your page a few times after you finished your settings, and also check it in logged-out mode, I had a few problems with sites being processed right on their first call, but broken afterwards.

A really tricky thing is the javascript-combining and minifying - if you are not 100% sure what you are doing, it can make your site a mess. But if you do - hello PageSpeed :)